# How can I use validation only for special numbers

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have entity :

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "version")
private String version;
```

And I also need that the version should be only : 2,5,7,11 or 18.

If another, it will not valid for passing.

Example :

If the version equals 5, it is okay.

If the version equals 6, it is NOT okay.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate using @Pattern annotation. See this [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-regular-expression-validation#:%7E:text=The%20Spring%20MVC%20Validation%20allows,pass%20it%20with%20the%20annotation.). For your case:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;  
@NotNull
@Column(name = "version")
@Pattern(regexp="^(2|5|7|11)$",message="Invalid Version")  
private String version;
```

This should work.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks!
But if I want to do the same only with Integer values? ( not String )

Comment: as far as i know, you can just annotate min-max values.

Comment: Got it, so then I am going to write own annotation for this)